# Select option arrow , responsive position

Tags: html, css

I need to style the arrow of the select option to looks like this

[image]

I found many related answers but all with position absolute - which limits the position to float naturally , so if i need the input to be responsive - it will lose it's position each time the resolution will change.

So i was thinking of maybe create 2 divs - one contains the select option and to it's left - div contains the custom arrow. But i can't position the arrow div close enough to the select option so it'll be clickable.....

Here is what i've done so far...

```
    <div class="modify_search">
      <div class="search_wrapper">
        <div class="search_header">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <p>QUAND</p>
            <div class="search_left">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span>DU</span></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control search_input" />
                <div class="input-group-addon input_icon"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search_right">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span>AU</span></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control search_input" />
                <div class="input-group-addon input_icon"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="search_profil">

            <div class="search_profil_cont">

              <p>PROFIL</p>
              <div class="foo1">
                <select class="search_select">
                  <option>Salarie</option>
                  <option>Salarie</option>
                  <option>Salarie</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="foo2">^</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search_footer_btn"><span class="search_btn">foo </span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the css :

```
    .search_input {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 1.4vw;
      box-shadow: none;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .search_input:focus {
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    .modify_search {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 5%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }

    .search_left,
    .search_right {
      border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    }

    .search_left {
      width: 48%;
      float: left;
    }

    .search_right {
      width: 48%;
      float: right;
    }

    /* .search_profil {
      float: left;
    } */
    .search_icon{
      float:left;
      width:50%;

    }

    .search_profil select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }

    .search_header {
      position: relative;
      height: 80%;
      padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
    }

    .search_footer_btn {
      height: 20%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #49c8c1;
    }

    .input-group-addon {
      background-color: white;
      border: none;
    }

    .input-group-addon > i:before {
      content: "\f073";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    .input_icon:after {
      content: "\f073";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    .input-group-addon span {
      font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      vertical-align: sub;
    }

    .search_select{
      border:none;
      outline:none;
      width:100%;
    }

    .search_select:foucs{
      border:none;
      outline:none;
    }
    .foo1{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
    }

    .foo2{
       float:left;
      width:50%;
    }
```

And the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/e558we47/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an image as a background to the select, and add a padding so that the text won't overflow your arrow.

Example of styling a select with a custom dropdown arrow:

```
select {
    padding: 39px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #9DC418;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(../assets/images/ui/pilned.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

You should also add this bit of code, to support IE browsers, and tell them to remove their original dropdown arrow:

```
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```